# Logged user object is all string

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm studying passing Laravel logged username to vuejs.
I use Laravel 10 And Vuejs 3 Composition API.

I searched at web and wrote below code. Currently, I can get Logged user info like this
However, I can't get just username.

> app.blade.php

```
 <meta name="user" content="{{ Auth::user() }}">
```

> index.vue

```
 {{ loggedUser }}

  <scrpt setup>
   import useCompanies from "@/composables/companies";
   import { onMounted } from "vue";

   const loggedUser = document.querySelector("meta[name='user']").getAttribute('content')
   console.log(typeof loggedUser)

 </script>
```

I checked the type of this object. It was String. And it is all combined one string.

> {"id":1,"name":"xxxxxxxxxx","email":"xxxx@xxxxx.com","branch":"\xxx\xxx"...

I would like to display Logged username only.
Could someone teach me what is wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Dear bassxzero
Thank you very much. I can successfully get user name. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract just the user name from the JSON string you've stored in the `meta` tag in your Laravel view and pass it to your Vue.js component, you can follow these steps:

1. In your Laravel `app.blade.php`, pass only the user name as a separate `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="user_name" content="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
```

2. In your Vue.js `index.vue` component, extract the user name from the `meta` tag:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ loggedUserName }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const loggedUserName = ref('');

onMounted(() => {
  const metaTag = document.querySelector("meta[name='user_name']");
  if (metaTag) {
    loggedUserName.value = metaTag.getAttribute('content');
  }
});
</script>
```

With these changes, you are passing only the user name from Laravel to Vue.js, and in your Vue component, you extract and display just the user name.

Comment: NULL exception will occur in case no user is logged in. Before accessing name, you must check if the user is logged in. You can use null check operator as: ``{{ Auth::user()?->name }}``

Comment: Dear @Aliif Thank you so much. I learned a lot!

Comment: Dear @OMi Shah I understood. Thank you very much.